# How can I launch Internet Explorer in Selenium WD 3.4?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

Here is the error:

> Error:
>
> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
>
> 3.14.0.0
>
> Listening on port 37557
>
> Only local connections are allowed

Here is my code:

```
 WebDriver driver=null;
 String browser= "ie";
 if(browser.equals("Chrome"))
 {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver=new ChromeDriver();
     driver.manage().window().maximize();   
     driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
 }
 else 
     if(browser.equals("ie"))
     {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\vdhanorkar\\Documents\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
         driver =new InternetExplorerDriver();
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this article](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver):

*The HTTP server started by the IEDriverServer.exe sets an access control list to only accept connections from the local machine, and disallows incoming connections from remote machines. At present, this cannot be changed without modifying the source code to the IEDriverServer.exe. To run the Internet Explorer driver on a remote machine, use the Java standalone remote server in connection with your language binding's equivalent of RemoteWebDriver.*